# Javascript Cannot Change Value in Inputbox when combobox is changed to speicifc text

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML Code

```js
      function getSelectValue()
    {
      
        if (document.getElementById("UserLocation").value == "Others"){
            document.getElementById("location").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("lbllocation").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("location").value=="Empty"
            alert("Hello World")
        }
        else {

            var selectedValue = document.getElementById("UserLocation").value;
            document.getElementById("location").value = selectedValue
            document.getElementById("location").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("lbllocation").style.display = "none";
            alert("Goodbye")
        }
                        
    }
    getSelectValue();
```

```html
 <select id="UserLocation" name="ddlselect" onchange="getSelectValue()">
        <option value="default">------Select---------</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="Others">Others</option>
        
    </select>
    
    <br>
    <label id="lbllocation">Please Specify</label>
    <input type="text" id="location" name="usrLocation" value="123">
```

So all is working except for this command

```
document.getElementById("location").value=="Empty"
```

in the if statement when I choose the `"Others"` from the combobox the value of location/input box is not changing to `"Empty"`. I already try `.innerHTML`, `.text` but none is working? Can you guys explain me why its not working?

Comment: It should be = not ==. document.getElementById("location").value="Empty"

Comment: `document.getElementById("location").value = "Empty"`. Two `==` are for comparison, one for assigning.

Answer (score 1):

You are using '==' instead of '=' for assignment.

Change

```
document.getElementById("location").value == "Empty";
```

To

```
document.getElementById("location").value = "Empty";
```